# Ensure the allocation of memory is of the right size

Tags: c, memory, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I seem to have a problem that I cant comprehend, the lab assistants said "Your memory allocation will not allocate the correct size, you need to use the size of the type itself instead of the variable.".

I have tried to use `sizeof (struct object)` like this `printf("%d", sizeof(struct object));`to see the size and it returns `36`. In the allocation the size is the same as the `struct object` so I am kinda lost to why it would allocate wrong size. The allocation seems to work for me correctly when I run it, and in the debugger it doesn't show any errors, so if anyone could have a look, I would really appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NameLength 20
#define UnitLenght 10

struct object
{
    char name[NameLength];
    float amount;
    char unit[UnitLenght];
};
struct inventory
{
    struct object *add;
    int nrOfobject;
};

void allocateMemory(struct inventory *allItem);

int main(void)
{
    struct inventory shopping = {NULL, 0};
    allocateMemory(&shopping);

return 0;
}

void allocateMemory(struct inventory *allItem)
{
    struct object *tempurary;
    if (allItem->nrOfobject == 0)
        tempurary = (struct object *)calloc(1, sizeof(*tempurary));
    else
        tempurary = (struct object *)realloc(allItem->add, sizeof(*tempurary)*(allItem->nrOfobject +1));
    allItem->add = tempurary;
}
```

Comment: `tempurary = (struct object *)calloc(1, sizeof(*tempurary));` is OK yet could be reduced to `tempurary = calloc(1, sizeof *tempurary);` and "tempurary" --> "temporary"

Comment: Lab assistants can be wrong too. `sizeof(*tempurary)` is the same as `sizeof(*(struct object *)`, which is the same as `sizeof(struct object)`.  In this case they are (unless you need to allocate more than the size of `struct object`.

Comment: A potential problem with `allocateMemory()` --> I'd expect a `llItem->nrOfobject++;` someplace.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes I in my other function that didnt have any problems where I add an object the `nrOfobject` gets updated like you showed so that `realloc` can add more space

Comment: Code looks valid except for the observation that chux made about incrementing the nrOfobject. I don't think there's a good reason to have the 0 case special: `allItem->add = realloc(allItem->add, sizeof(object) * ++allItem->nrOfObject);` seems to do everything. (If you pass a NULL to realloc, it's the same as malloc).

Comment: It's weird to use calloc and realloc together. If the memory needs clearing, then the extra space allocated by realloc should also be cleared. If not, malloc (rather than calloc) is normal.

Comment: Of course `sizeof(struct object)` and `sizeof(*tempurary)` is the same. The idea behind the recommendation to prefer `sizeof(*tempurary)` is that the variable name will normally appear near the allocation as in `tempurary = calloc(1, sizeof(*tempurary));` while the declaration that specifies its type (as `struct object *tempurary;`) might be somewhere else in bigger programs. If you accidentally specify a wrong variable (e.g. from copy&paste), this error would be easier to spot than if you accidentally specify a wrong type.

Comment: @Bodo so I should just do `sizeof(struct object)` instead ?

Comment: @Jacob No, keep what you have.  If the type name happens to change it's less error prone.

Comment: @Jacob your way is considered better. Ask lab assistant to explain why he thinks it will give wrong size

Comment: @Jacob **No. Prefer using variable names to get the size, because it will be easier to spot errors.** If you do it correct, both the type and the variable will give you the same `sizeof` result. But consider possible errors like `tempurary = calloc(1, sizeof(*some_variable));` vs. `tempurary = calloc(1, sizeof(struct some_type));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> void allocateMemory(struct inventory *allItem)
> {
>     struct object *tempurary;
>     if (allItem->nrOfobject == 0)
>         tempurary = (struct object *)calloc(1, sizeof(*tempurary));
>     else
>         tempurary = (struct object *)realloc(allItem->add, sizeof(*tempurary)*(allItem->nrOfobject +1));
>     allItem->add = tempurary;
> }
> ```

The size looks correct, although I would remove the unnecessary cast, and the clearing of the first element (since we don't zero-out the subsequent ones).  Also, check the result of `realloc()` before overwriting the pointer (otherwise we can leave a memory leak):

```
int allocateMemory(struct inventory *allItem)
{
    struct object *temporary;
    if (allItem->nrOfobject == 0) {
        temporary = malloc(sizeof *temporary);
    } else {
        temporary = realloc(allItem->add, (sizeof *temporary)*(allItem->nrOfobject + 1));
    }
    if (!temporary) {
        return 0;
    }
    allItem->add = temporary;
    return ++allItem->nrOfobject;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `allItem->add[allItem->nrOfobject] = (struct object){0};` or the like before the `return`.

Comment: Yes, if this were [codereview.se], I'd address the invariants properly.  But I'm already overstepping scope for SO, I think.